# Peak detection and smoothing data

Tags: machine-learning, smoothing

I'm working on smoothing data. But I want to retain the peak actual value and draw the actual value along with other smoothed data. And I use the Robust peak detection algorithm but it didn't work the way I want. How can I smoothing data retain peak actual value?

Here is a sketch:
[image: hand-drawn sketch of desired plot showing original and modified sequences of values]

In this picture, the blue line is the original data graph and I want to convert this like red, which means I want the actual value of the peaks and smoothed value of other data.

Comment: What is smoothing data? What are peaks? What are you trying to do here and why?

Comment: Data smoothing is a statistical technique that involves removing outliers from a data set in order to make a pattern more visible.
smooth a data set is to create an approximating function that attempts to capture important patterns in the data.

Comment: From the cartoon, it looks like all you're doing is replacing blue values below some threshold with a fixed value (the red line).

Comment: Which robust peak detection algorithm?  Can you give "toy" data that we can process?  How do you determine the non-peak value is about 15?  Are you working in R, Python, or MatLab?

Comment: Robust peak detection algorithm using z-scores  ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data/43512887#43512887 ) I made some changes in this algorithm before I using in python.